# Ruby on Rails Active Record inner join not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 models: Engagement, user. Engagement basically refers to the items booked by the user. each engagement is for a specific user. user in engagement has a foreign key. I want to join engagement with user so that i can see the details of the user.

Here are my models

```
class Engagement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food_item  
  belongs_to :user
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :engagements
    has_many :food_item, through: :engagements
end
```

I am running below query:

```
Engagement.joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = engagements.user_id")
```

It is not joining both the tables.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what sql doesn't it produce?

Comment: Do you recieve an error message?  If so can you share?

Comment: Just a comment, Rails uses inner join by default, so you could do Engagement.joins(:user)

Comment: He thanks for prompt replies, I  not getting any error messages from the query but the issue is I am also not getting the users information.

Comment: @marcelo the query you mentioned is also fetching me the same result. Thanka fro suggestions anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is right.
You're doing a inner join and only returning engagements that have a relation to user.

To return the user data you should do something like this: `Engagement.select('tasks.*, users.*').joins(:user)`. This way the object will have engagement and user attributes. But that is not the Rails way.

The "correct" way is:

```rb
engagements = Engagement.includes(:user)
engagements.first.user # this will return the user data
```

This way you're getting all engagements and preloading the user data, this way avoiding n + 1 queries ([Eager-loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)) ;)

Comment: The problem with includes way is it will do another query with an IN clause on the associated table. But take a scenario where we just want to fetch one row from the DB and want to get all associations via an inner join. If we do includes there, it will anyway do separate queries for each association. In that case, should we do the first way you described?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Engagement.joins(:users)`

It should work.

Comment: @giovani above query is also not fetching the user data. It is giving me the same result which the query I mentioned in the question